# How do you remove DNA/RNA from plastics?

Tags: biochemistry

I want to know how to make plastic containers free of DNA & RNA? this is just for knowledge

Comment: Use disposable containers like Eppendorf tubes and Falcons, that is by far the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

Lab cleaning solutions can be bought which remove/destroy nucleic acids such as [this one](http://www.mobio.com/lab-accessories/ultraclean-lab-cleaner.html). UV is another [technique for destroying DNA](http://discoveryscientific.com/products-by-area/thermal-cycling/UV-sterilization-cabinets-DNA-PCR-decontamination-workstations-amplification). And bleach is used to remove contaminant DNA in [ancient DNA studies](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16182949).

Searching for a DNA/RNA lab cleaning protocol would be a good idea to - [something like this](http://www.bowserlab.org/benthic_ecology/molececol/godliness.htm).

Comment: Both the 'this one' link is not working and the 'something like this' aren't working, would you mind providing updated links?